# A function is returning a dataframe whose data will change everytime I run the code, I need to store this dataframe in a time series fashion

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, concatenation

I am new to python please help me.
I have a function that is returning a dataframe whose value will change everytime, I run the code.
I need to store this dataframe into another data frame so my overall output is like a time series data as the dataframe has a timestamp in it too.

```
def Vega_dict():
    Sum_CE_Vega = Final_df.loc[Final_df['instrumentType'] == 'CE', 'vega'].sum()
    Sum_PE_Vega = Final_df.loc[Final_df['instrumentType'] == 'PE', 'vega'].sum()
    Vega_dict = []
    Vega_dict.append(Time)
    Vega_dict.append(Sum_CE_Vega)
    Vega_dict.append(Sum_PE_Vega)
    Vega_df = pd.DataFrame(Vega_dict)
    Vega_df = Vega_df.T
    Vega_df.columns = ["Time", "Sum of OTM CE", "Sum of OTM PE"]
    return Vega_df
```

Can someone please help me with this.

Current output is

```
       Time Sum of OTM CE Sum of OTM PE
0  21:43:53    163.835972     154.28453

Desired Output
    Time  Sum of OTM CE  Sum of OTM PE
0  21:43:53  x1              y1
1  21:43:59  x2              y2
```

So that everytime I run the code new value will get added at the bootom of the dataframe.

Please help

Comment: if the data is the homogeneous, then why not just keep appending the original dataframe with the new data ?  it would be cleaner to do this.

Comment: how can we do this, i was thinking of this method but not able to code it pls help

Answer (score 1):

what about saving your returned dataframe in an array and you do pd.concat.

```
dataset_list = []
#calling 3 times
while i < 4:
  i += 1
  dataset_list.append(Vega_dict())
final_dataset = pd.concat(dataset_list, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: i agree with this.   or, even better, just modify the original existing dataframe with new data each time.

Comment: thanks but the data in the dataframe will keep refreshing after every 20 sec so how can i store it .

Comment: @denise,  ...i do a very similar process. i create chunks like this `df_chuck = pd.DataFrame(client_trades)` and then concat the chuncks to the existing dataframe like this: `df = pd.concat([df, df_chuck], ignore_index=True)`....

Answer (score 0):

I do a similar process to @Sandrine. And the refreshing that you ask about in the comments works perfectly well (and fast) this way.

However, my approach would be to create `chunks` of new dataframes and then `concat` to the existing dataframe like this:

```py
df_chuck = pd.DataFrame('whatever data you like...')

# check that the new dataframe contains data
if len(df_chuck)>1:
    ...
    # add the chunck to the existing dataframe
    df = pd.concat([df, df_chuck], ignore_index=True)
```

Importantly, **both methods ultimately concatenate** (`concat`) the data.

- One method does this via an append.
- and the other method does this via chuncks.

Comment: I have created a empty dataframe and tried to concatenate the function returning the dataframe but its still not working

`df_vega_final = pd.DataFrame()
df_vega_final = pd.concat([df_vega_final,Vega_dict()], ignore_index = True)
print(df_vega_final)`

what i am missing here

Comment: @denise,  you need to fill the dataframe with the new data (some rows of data) otherwise you will just have an empty dataframe !

Comment: I have tried to create a new data frame like this
`df_vega_store = pd.DataFrame(Vega_dict())`
and then tried to add back this dataframe to the previous function

but it is throwing an error 
name 'df_vega_store' is not defined

Comment: you should probably start a new question starting with this error. in particular showing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  the reason that i say this is that both answers proposed satisfy the original question, so really this is a new question.